# Line Break for Array in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I want to ask on how do to break the lines of arrays. I was making a questionnaire, when I encountered this. What I just want to do is literally just break the lines of the codes so that it won't be very long

I don't know where to start, so here is my first code:

```
  Public Sub showQuestion()
    Dim letter
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer

Randomize
question = Array("A programming language originally developed by James Gosling at Sun Microsystems", "A programming language from Microsoft", "Determines when the user wants to do something such as exit the application or begin printing", "Property information", "GUI information and private code")
answer = Array("Java", "Visual_Basic", "Command_Button", "Property_page", "Form")

question = Array("Specifies the background color of the control", "Generally, specifies whether or not a control has a border", "Determines whether or not the control can respond to user-generated events", "For controls displaying text, specifies the font (name, style, size, etc.) to be applied to the displayed text")
answer = Array("BackColor", "BorderStyle", "Enabled", "Font")

question = Array("Specifies the color of text or graphics to be displayed in the control", "Specifies the height of the control in pixels", "The string value used to refer to the control in code", "Specifies the graphic to be displayed in the control")
answer = Array("ForeColor", "Height", "Name", "Image")

qno = Int(Rnd * (UBound(question) + 1))
ReDim ans(Len(answer(qno)), 2)

lblquestion.Caption = question(qno)

For X = 0 To Len(answer(qno)) - 1
    ans(X, 1) = Mid$(answer(qno), X + 1, 1)

Next X

For Y = 0 To Len(answer(qno)) - 1
    If ans(Y, 1) = "_" Then
        ans(Y, 2) = Chr$(32)
    Else
        ans(Y, 2) = "*"
    End If
Next Y

loadHint
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking but you can try adding vbCrLf

Comment: Use a _ for a line break

Comment: @MarkHall - How, exactly? (sorry)

Comment: See the answer that I just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your clarification, you can break the line by using an underscore(_) something like this.

```
question = Array("A programming language originally developed by James Gosling at Sun Microsystems", _
                 "A programming language from Microsoft", _
                 "Determines when the user wants to do something such as exit the application or begin printing", _
                 "Property information", "GUI information and private code")  

answer = Array("Java", "Visual_Basic", "Command_Button", _
               "Property_page", "Form")
```

Comment: @MarkJ You are right, never done it though old habits die hard :)